# How to make a wxpython Bitmap Button with only image and no extra pixels and border around image

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to use an image as a button in wxpython. What I want is that there should only be a bitmap and no other border or any extra pixel around the button. I would really only want to capture a click on a bitmap, so maybe I do not need an actual button. "Pressing down" the button is hence not required.

One option that I am using a PlateButton with platebutton.PB_STYLE_NOBG which works fine only when it is displaying the image without any mouse hover or clicks. Now when I hover the button, what I want is a shadowed image of same image(only image and no border or anything), but what I get is a square border around my image.

My code :

```
import wx.lib.platebtn as platebutton


imageButton = platebutton.PlateButton(self._ribbon,wx.ID_NEW, bmp = wx.Bitmap("image.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY), pos = (0,0), size = (37,17), style= platebutton.PB_STYLE_DEFAULT | platebutton.PB_STYLE_NOBG)
```

Comment: You might want to accept the answers to some of your earlier questions before looking for too much more help.   That's the way it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly use static bitmap and capture the mouse event in this bitmap.

try this:

```
     sBitMap = wx.StaticBitmap(self._ribbon, -1, wx.Bitmap("image.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY), (0, 0), (37,17))
     sBitMap.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)

def OnLeftDown(self, e):
    print "OnLeftDown"
```

Edit:

Fetch the size from the source image and use it to create the static bitmap

```
sBitMap = wx.StaticBitmap(self._ribbon, -1, wx.Bitmap("image.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY), (0, 0), (bmp.GetWidth(), bmp.GetHeight()))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it works . But I am still getting a white color rectangle around my image and I don't want that to happen. I just want to put an image on a solid background. Is there any flag to do that. Thanks... Also, I want to show a dropdown menu on image click like in MS office left top image, is it possible to do that.

Comment: @user3248521 This probably because your image is smaller than (37, 17)

Comment: Thanks it works... But I am using it on ribbon with ribbon as parent and not the frame, so that is why I am having problem. Using frame as parent, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the GenBitmapButton from wx.lib.buttons

```
path="path to bitmap"
size=(size of bitmap)
b=GenBitmapButton(Parent,wx.ID_ANY, bitmap=wx.Bitmap(path),
                  style=wx.NO_BORDER|wx.BU_EXACTFIT,size=size)
```

This is doing the trick just fine and I have bitmaps lined up with no spacing between them for buttons.